# Is zap full scan supports reading multiple URLs from a file directly?

Tags: zap

-t target         target URL including the protocol, e.g. https://www.example.com
I want to pass multiple urls within txt or csv file for full scan , is that possible?

fired with this error : Target must start with 'http://' or 'https://'
Usage: zap-full-scan.py -t  [options]
-t target         target URL including the protocol, e.g. https://www.example.com

Comment: To enable ZAP full scan to read multiple URLs from a file, modify the script to iterate over URLs in the file, ensuring each starts with 'http://' or 'https://'. Then invoke the full scan command for each valid URL individually. Implement error handling and validation for robustness.

Answer (score 1):

No, the ZAP packages scans only support one URL at a time. As mentioned in the first comment, you can write a script which loops over a file and calls the packaged scan for each URL.

The ZAP Automation ramework is more flexible, but we still recommend calling that once per target.